# Delay the appearance of "Have you considered accepting ..." message

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

On june 6th I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249425/why-does-drawimageunscaled-cause-flickering-when-used-from-wm-ncpaint). After about ten days, someone posted an answer. This was (at the time I'm writing this) thirteen hours ago. When I logged onto stackoverflow this morning, the first thing that caught my eye was this *Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?* message, which I saw at about the same time as the message telling me I had a new answer to a question.

Now, while I can appreciate the notion of reminding people to accept answers if they're correct, some answers given may lead to a correct solution of a problem but do need research. Basically, to allow for this, I'm asking for delaying the appearance of the *"Have you considered..."* message for a certain period of time after the first answer to a question is posted, simply because it's not always possible to tell by looking at it if the answer will work or not.

**EDIT** Looking at this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) on *New Question Asker Features*, maybe three days would be a good delay time. That'd almost account for weekends - at least for those people who still got them ;-)

Comment: I'd really appreciate if those people that downvote would explain why they're doing it.

Comment: It's because they don't agree with your proposal.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, I can see that, but from my point of view it makes sense, otherwise I wouldn't have posted. So my question is _why_ they don't agree.

Comment: Well I agree. There's a fine line between encouraging people to accept answers, which I totally support, and badgering them.