# Calculating accepted answer percentage

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

Taken from [Jeff Attwoods blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) on *New Question Asker Features*:

```
...
* Questions must be more than 3 days old.
* Questions must have at least 1 answer.
...
```

I'm asking to change this to:

```
...
* Questions must be more than 3 days old.
* Questions must have at least 1 answer that's accepted or more than 3 days old.
...
```

My point is, if someone posts a first answer to a question that's older than three days, it will instantly lower your accept rate, even if you haven't logged onto stackexchange for two days to actually see the answer. Taking the answer age into account would add a bit of transparency in this respect I think.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if those people that downvote would explain why they're doing it. Whoops, there's an [echo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95455/delay-the-appearance-of-have-you-considered-accepting-message) here ...

Comment: It's because they don't agree with your proposal. It's because they don't agree with your proposal. It's because they don't agree with your proposal. It's because they don't agree with your proposal. It's because they don't agree .... (hey, you're right ;))

Comment: Declined given that [accept rate is no longer shown on a usercard on a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why this is really necessary.

Your accept rate would come into consideration only when you ask a new question. At that point, if you've marked all applicable answers your rate should be fine. So that your rate would only drop *after* you've already asked your question.

And even if it did drop, then so what? Surely if you've marked those applicable questions, your rate would be above 50% - 60%. Anything above that range is usually ok. I only look at the accept rate when it's in the orange range, so any question that got a recent answer shouldn't affect your overall rate.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm just being picky, but I appreciate a decent answer over a non-explanatory downvote, expecially here where things are a lot more argumentative than on SO :)

Comment: @takrl don't take the downvotes personally. Meta is for discussions, so there is not right/wrong. Just agree/disagree :)

Comment: But it's _so_ difficult when you're used to the regular _SO_ :)