# Check when answers are posted before displaying the message "Have you considered accepting an answer...?"

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delay the appearance of “Have you considered accepting …” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95455/delay-the-appearance-of-have-you-considered-accepting-message)

I asked a question on January 24th and got an answer on January 31st. The answer was accompanied by the following message.

[image: screenshot]

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this
>   question?

I think that this message should check the time that the latest answer was posted.

Comment: On second thought, this may be a dupe of [Delay the appearance of “Have you considered accepting …” message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95455/162705).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure precisely what you're asking, but I *think* it's

> Why am I getting this message even though my question already has an answer?

The reason is that even though your question has an answer, you haven't *accepted* it yet. Once you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/162705), that message should go away.

If, however, your question is instead

> Why am I getting this message *before I've even had a chance to read the answer to my question?*

[A very similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95455/162705) has already been asked before.

Comment: True, but that message shouldn't appear when the first and only answer was posted only 22 minutes ago.

Comment: It was his question, and he says it was posted on the 24th.

Comment: why i am getting this message just after getting an answer. i think it should appear after 12hours or 24hours.

Comment: @Parag: The idea is your question has been open for 7 days and it's asking you to start a bounty, even though you just got an answer less than half an hour ago. The logic for the message appears flawed.

Comment: @Chris where is the answer?